# Text inside of <span> wraps too early because of margin

Tags: css

I have a paragraph that has several span-elements inside of it. For design purposes, the text inside of those spans should wrap at any arbitrary place to the new line. This is achieved by adding a soft hyphen (\u200B) between all characters. Also, the spans should have a gap of 50px between them, which is achieved by a right margin.

```js
const addBreakCharacters = () => {
  const breakChar = "\u200B";
  const homeContainer = document.querySelector(".home-container");
  const itemList = homeContainer.querySelectorAll("span");

  itemList.forEach((item) => {
    const text = item.textContent;
    const newText = text.split("").join(breakChar);
    item.textContent = newText;
  });
};

addBreakCharacters();
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  word-wrap: anywhere;
  white-space: normal;
  hyphens: none;
}
p.title,
span.title {
  color: #ff0000;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.home-container > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="home-container">
  <span class="title">Studio A</span>
  <span>Adrian Scherrer</span>
  <span>Altendorferstrasse 20a</span>
  <span>CH-9470 Buchs</span>
  <a href="phone:+41817561415">
    <span>+41 81 756 14 15</span>
  </a>
  <a href="phone:+41765780940">
    <span>+41 76 578 09 40</span>
  </a>
  <a href="mailto:i@studioa.ch">
    <span>i@studioa.ch</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

The problem is, that the last letter of the text already wraps to the new line, although there is still plenty of space on the current line. The margin-right of 50px somehow causes this behaviour.

In the screenshot below you can see that the character "a" already wraps to the second line, although it should stay on the first line. This example is reproducible at the screen width of 830px using the provided snippet in the full screen view. I guess it happens because there is less than 50px (the defined margin) of space left on the first line, which somehow causes the last character to break to the new line, although the margin takes it's effect after the character (yellow rectangle). It seems like the right margin and the last character always stick together.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXDfF.png)

How can I achieve that the text only wraps when the space of the line is completely filled, regardless of the defined gap between the span elements? Looking at the provided screenshot, the expected behaviour would be that the character "a" stays on the first line, the margin fills the remaining space on the first line and the next span starts on the new line.

Comment: Hi, it would make it easier to help if you included an example of the HTML, preferably corresponding to the screenshot. Also if you could describe what you want to happen if a span starts a newline - I assume it should not have that 50px gap on its left, is that right? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for putting the runnable snippet into your question. You may need a bit of JavaScript to do this. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @AHaworth - Thanks for your input. I included a working example with HTML, nevertheless the error is only reproducible at a specific screen width, which is why the screenshot is still needed. I hope the question is easier to understand now.

Comment: @AHaworth - Yes, the use of JavaScript is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox.

```js
// get 30 random words from this API - https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/home
fetch('https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=30')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // wrap each word in an <li> tag and replace contents of <ul>
    document.querySelector('.home-container').innerHTML = data.map(a => `<span>${a}</span>`).join('')
  })
```

```css
.home-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.home-container>* {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-container"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't lead to the expected behaviour. The gap should always be 50px (no justify-content) and the words should wrap at every arbitrary place. Here the words don't wrap at all.